# remove if not matched in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database where i want to clean up a table but i do not know how to compare against other table entrys and hope someone can help.

One table in the database is called "stats". in the table "Stats" there is a row called "Page_title" which holds an ID number. The same ID number should exist in the table "url,id" otherwise that entry from "stats" should be removed, how can this be done?

[Please see this image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okNfC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a sub select:

```
delete from stats where page_title not in (select id from shorturl)
```